# SMS URL for users not using the default SMS app

Tags: android, html, sms, href

After reading user data from user agent, i use customized href link for all android users to open SMS app with predefined receiver number and body.

```
<p>Base test <a href="sms:+12345?body=Lorem%20ipsum">TEST</a></p>
```

I works perfectly with default SMS app, but more users starterted using Messenger and other custom sms apps for sending and reciving SMS.
With Textra etc. numb and body are passed correctly, Mood passses body correctly but adds // before receiver number 
But if users are using Messenger as default SMS app links doesn't work at all.
After clicking on a link Messenger doesn't respond, like nothing happened.
Anybody have idea how should link look for Messenger to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

Extraordinary question friend. I had a similar problem, and my solution was to use javascript and onclick event. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The closest i got to finding solution is

```
<p>Base test <a href="intent:+39999123456?body=Lore%20ipsum#Intent;scheme=smsto;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;S.android.extra.TEXT=Lorem%20ipsum;end"> Open Messenger</a></p>
```

This link opens Messenger and passes correct number from link but i still can't pass SMS content.

I am done with this but i hope this may help someone else

(tested on Android 7.1, Messenger 157.0.0.21.89, Mozilla and Chrome)